# Not getting deleted record from salesforce using queryAll() function

Tags: php, salesforce

Hello Everyone,
I am unable to get deleted record using queryAll() function of force.com toolkit for php here is my code

```
 $query ="select Id from Account   ";
$mySforceConnection->setQueryOptions($options);
                        $response = $mySforceConnection->queryAll($query);
                        $queryResult = new QueryResult($response);
```

From the Above code I got the same results as I was getting in query().
I am using partner wsdl.

Comment: Maybe somebody deleted these records from the Recycle Bin? Do you see them in the web interface? What happens when query for `SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE isDeleted = true`?

Comment: @eyescream Thanks for comment.Query  return two  record

Comment: I think you have more records in the system then. By default queryAll returns both existing & deleted data and you'll get first chunk of say 2000 records... These guys will be eventually returned after you'll call [queryMore()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm). Or really run the query for deleted items only (`WHERE isDeleted = true`)

Comment: I have 4018 record then i deleted 2 record  but when I use my code and echo $queryResult->size it was showing 4016 but after that day now every thing is going fine  that why i was confused I think salesforce take time frame to complete delete function .Please correct me if I was wrong .One more thing is that during one day period I was unable to see that two record in salesforce query editor

Comment: Normal queries (which editor do you use?) by default respect the Recycle Bin so if something gets deleted it disappears from query results. The equivalent of "queryAll" in Apex/SOQL is `SELECT Id, Name FROM Account ALL ROWS`. External applications can either user query/queryAll difference to achieve same result or I think in REST API you just fire it with "ALL ROWS" slapped at the end... But looks like you use SOAP API